# PHP running out of memory with Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-aurora

I'm busy migrating a customer application written in PHP/MySQL from Hetzner to AWS. Everything works fine but a few scripts. These scripts are poorly written and loop through millions of records, creating hundreds of local variables in each run of the loop, writing each row to an excel file, opening another file, writing a status update and closing a file in each run of the loop. The script is spawned as an independent process using `shell_exec` from the main web application.

When I first tested the script on EC2, it crashed quite quickly as the php `memory_limit` parameter was set to `128M` on my EC2 instance. The error was similar to the one below:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)
```

I increased the `memory_limit` from `128M` to `256M`, then to `512M`, then to `1024M`, `4096M` and eventually set to `-1` to see where the problem lies.

Setting it to `-1` did initially seemed to work but it then froze the entire instance (t2.micro). I then realized it was because of lack of swap space that system memory limits are being reached so just for testing purposes, I added a swap space of `4GB` and set `memory_limit` to `-1`. This did work as expected and the script never crashed but as the script ran, it became progressively slower. For instance, it wrote the first 10% of records to excel file much faster than the 10% after 50%. All this while I watched the memory usage expand to 6 GB.

Below are screenshots from `htop` while the script was running:

[image]

[image]

I'm using the default `php.ini` that comes php installation except for `memory_limit` which is set to -1.

However, when I run this *very* same script on another server (Hetzner shared hosting in this case), the server somehow limits the memory usage and the script runs fine on `128M` of `memory_limit` setting. Although this is not entirely true (as confirmed by `htop` on the server), it seems like it does not crash on the server with much less memory/swap space than on my EC2 instance.

Below are screenshots from `htop` running on Hetzner:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The third screenshot was taken towards the end of the script - and as you can see the memory didn't change much between when it started and the end. Here's the `php.ini` settings from the server:

```
display_errors=1
memory_limit=128M
max_execution_time=90
max_input_vars=3500
upload_max_filesize=64M
post_max_size=64M
allow_url_fopen=0
```

The database and code base are exact replicas in both instances.The resultant excel file size is about 225MB in both cases.

So, any ideas what might be causing this behavior and how should I go about fixing it on my EC2 instance?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The best thing you could do is make the script more efficient. The Hetzner instance is also using about 5G of memory so there must be something overriding the php.ini on that server as well.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but the Hetzner instance is not using 5 GB for the script ONLY. Like I said, its a shared instance and the `4686/15964MB` that you see is memory usage across *all* accounts/processes running on the server (not just mine). If you look at VIRT and RES columns for PHP script in EC2 and Hetzner screenshots - there seems a huge difference in terms of memory being consumed.

Comment: Yeah sorry I misread that, is the Hetzner server virtualised or physical?

Comment: No worries. Its a 'Shared' hosting package - but it looks like a physical server shared between multiple users/customers (Not a virtualized machine). I have sent them an email to clarify.

Comment: There are a bunch of variables which change memory usage with a php script, usually these are different versions of PHP or different enabled/configured extensions. I've also found physical servers tend to use less memory than virtualised ones.

Comment: Any suggestions for further troubleshooting/debugging?

Comment: 2 recommendations I'd make are: compare the versions of php and installed extensions between the 2 servers and optimise the PHP script to release memory when it is finished using variables.

Comment: Your Hetzner server appears to have 16GiB of RAM and is using essentially none of its swap.  You can't compare this to a t2.micro with 1 GiB of RAM and heavy swapping to a small EBS volume.  Use a t2.xlarge to test. Verify that you have reasonable parity, *then* start scaling the instance down.

Answer (score 0):

> EasyPHP-Devserver-17-depanne-erreur Fatal error: Allowed memory size
> of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 471698889 bytes) in
> C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2425vc11x86x180705170153\eds-app-dashboard.php
> on line 77

**SOLUTION**

In my case, it was because Easyphp was trying to load a too large error.log file.

**Deleting** the server **log** file in eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2418x160331124251\logs
Test ok